# 2019 MacBook Air still sucks down battery when sleep

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, sleep-wake, power

Apples website says my 2019 MacBook Air has 30 day standby time and runs 12 hours on battery. My 2015 MacBook air (my first mac) actually got around 12 hours battery while using node, chrome, and sublime text (my usual tools at the time). I use to brag about it all the time and wouldn't plug it in until i was down to 5% battery. My 2015 model doesn't run as long as it did in 2015-2017 so i purchased a new one a month ago.

After a month of getting settled in with the 2019 mac I realize either the battery performance is lower quality, OS is sucking more resources in the background or my tools (node, chrome, and vs-code) are sucking more power. I only get about 6-7 hours of actual working time on average with my new mac which is only 1-2 hours longer than my old 2015 gets now even with true tone disabled. Both are running Mojave. What is the problem?

Also, over the last 8 days, my 2019 MacBook air has been on battery 7 days and 10 hours but only awake and working for 5 hours and the battery is at 9%. "enable power nap while on battery" is disabled as well as true tone. Excessive power consumption when the system is sleep was never a problem on my 2015 MacBook Air but it's a problem out of the box on my 2019 MacBook Air. Are there any new strategies for resolving this on newer macs? Do the [old tricks](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/166852/131717) apply to new macs?

Answer (score 1):

A while back Apple introduced something called "Power Nap."

Basically your Mac will still do some background tasks while asleep. I am guessing that this might be what is going on.

Go to

`System Preferences > Energy Saver`

and look for "Enable Power Nap while on battery power."

I would guess that it is checked, un-check it and see if that helps.

Also there is a good shareware app out there called Coconut Battery that will give you some detailed info on battery health and usage, you may want to look into that as well.